# Completion Handler/Event for NSCollectionView

Tags: swift, cocoa, appkit, nscollectionview

I'm building a collection view that is able to insert and remove a placeholder item. I'm using `performBatchUpdates` to dispatch either an `insertItems` or `deleteItems` call and the changes are executed correctly. There are properties I'd like to forward to my subclass of `NSCollectionViewItem` which, of course, requires access to the item. However, neither in the "completion" block, nor after the batch update block as a whole is the item actually available.

Inside the completion block and immediately afterwards, `visibleItems()` does not *yet* show the inserted item and it can not yet be retrieved by its valid index path; The `numberOfItems` method returns a correct item count.

```swift
func showEditablePlaceholder(with kind: AvailabilityInclination.Kind, intervalMode: AvailabilityEditableItemView.IntervalMode) {
    guard let indexPath = placeholderIndexPath else {
        return
    }

    showsEditablePlaceholder = true

    performBatchUpdates({
        insertItems(at: [indexPath])
    }) { didCompleteAnimations in
        // At this point, item should not be nil.
        let placeholderItem = self.item(at: indexPath) as? AvailabilityCollectionViewItem
        placeholderItem?.editableView?.inclinationKind = kind
        self.invalidateForEditablePlaceholder()
    }
}
```

At which point can I properly acquire the collection view item after performing batch updates? I thought the completion block would be included for that exact purpose.

Comment: What does `self.item(at: indexPath)` return?

Comment: Calling the method from the debugger at that point in time without the succeeding type cast returns `nil`.

Clarifying the example case here, the debugger produces the following output when I had 4 existing items and am then adding a new placeholder item: `indexPath == [0, 4]`, `numberOfItems(inSection: 0) == 5`.

Comment: Is `collectionView(_:itemForRepresentedObjectAt:)` called for the inserted item?

Comment: @Fretag, @Willeke: or have you tried the delegate method `collectionView:willDisplayItem:forRepresentedObjectAtIndexPath:` That will give you a reference to the item just before it's displayed (though of course you'll have lost the context in which the item was created...)

Comment: @Willeke I just checked: The delegate function `itemForRepresentedObjectAt` is called after the first block of `performBatchUpdates` but before the completion block. That's also where my assumption comes from, that the item should be available there, through the collection view.

Comment: @TedWrigley That's what I'm using as a workaround in the meantime. I've added a "middleware" block that I set for single-use before first part of `performBatchUpdates` is invoked. The data source that instantiates the item then passes the item in its middleware closure, allowing me to modify it immediately after creation while keeping the logic separate.

Comment: Does `collectionView(_:itemForRepresentedObjectAt:)` return the placeholder item? I tried your code and it works for me.

Comment: Yes, I said, besides this anomaly, the collection view works as expected and displays the correct items. My data source module returns the items before the completion block is called, they are still not retrievable until after the placeholder method has completed (https://imgur.com/a/YqURpI9). Calling the `collectionView(_:itemForRepresentedObjectAt:)` data source method instead of `item(at:)` would create a new item, not return the existing one.

Comment: @Freytag: hmmm... I'll point out that I don't actually see you add the placeholder item to the collection view in this code snip. CollViews want the object added to the model *before* `insertItems(at:)` is called, and this method doesn't do that (though maybe it happens elsewhere). `insertItems(at:)` is only meant to sync the model and the view. Also, I assume from the last line of your first paragraph that you tried moving the code out of the 'completion' block and into the 'update' block, right?

Comment: @TedWrigley Very right for you to point out — in this case, though, I've taken care of my data source before the updates and I'm aware of the required order. As I've said, the item does appear and is available some time after `performBatchUpdates ` has run, my issue is just, that I'd assume it should be available here and if I've misunderstood the completion handler of `performBatchUpdates`.

Comment: @Freytag: please, if you would, answer my last question directly. Did you try putting the code in the 'update' block instead of the 'completion' block? The purpose of a controller object is to mediate between the data source and the view. The 'update' block *must* be able to see both the data source and the view, otherwise they would not do the job they are designed to do.  I'm not so sure that's true of the completion block, which might be intended for general cleanup rather than detailed interaction. If the U block does not see your placeholder, then you've done something off adding it.

Comment: Of course, @TedWrigley. If I got you right, you want me to try acquire the collection view item from within the first block of `performBatchUpdates`. If you mean it like this https://gitlab.com/snippets/1879617, I get an assertion failure. I would also feel like this makes more sense not being available immediately as actions are batched and executed all at once after processing, there's even a predefined order to it. The "completion handler" would be more reasonable in my view.

Comment: Hmph, interesting. Well, as I read the docs, the point of this method is to update the UI. The datasource *should* be stable before this is called; this just synchronizes the CV's internal structures and animates changes in the UI. If you're getting that assertion error, it either means that your indexPath is pointing at the wrong place, or that the placeholder object hasn't been properly added to the data source. If it were me, I'd throw a couple of breakpoints in (at lines 9 and 13 in the clip you provided), and manually inspect the data source and index path to see what was going on.